Find a convergent series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ such that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}1-\frac{\sin a_n}{a_n}$ diverges
I was given a homework assignment that goes like this:
Let $a_n\neq0$ be a sequence such that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ converges. Show that the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (1-\frac{\sin(a_n)}{a_n})$:
a) Converges if $a_n$ is positive.
b) Can be both convergent or divergent if $a_n$ isn't necesarilly positive.
I was able to prove (a) using the limit comparison test.
Moving on to (b), this is trickier for me. For convergence it's easy, I just choose something like $a_n=\frac{1}{n^2}$ then use (a). However for divergence, I'm lost. I understand that I have to choose a series that is either negative or has some sort of sign alternation. But I have no clue on how to approach this.
Many thanks to the helpers.

You have to find a convergent series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ such that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n^2$  diverges.

Thanks, I got it. Had I looked at the way I proved (a) once more it would hit me. I just thought that I wouldn't be able to use the limit comparison test to show it since $a_n$ is not nonnegative, but because were talking about ${a_n}^2$, it would work. So the answer is $\frac{1}{\sqrt n}$ with alternating signs.
